# how to exctract extension in php

Tags: php, arrays, extract

I am trying to extract extension from string using php and then look inside array. It seems that i do get the extension but when i look inside array it does not work and I cant see a problem. Maybe you could suggest or point me. Thank you.

Here is the code:

```
$file = '/folder/subfolder/file.mp4' //It can be also a url with domain etc. basically anything

$extension = pathinfo($file);
$final_extension = strtolower($extension['extension']);

$fileArray = array("mp4","mp3");

if (in_array($final_extension, $fileArray)) {
    echo "Found!";
}
```

Comment: Works for me http://ideone.com/wjEove (after adding the semicolon to the first line)

Comment: yup. semicolon on the first line would make your script not work at all.

also try using `print_r()` on the `$extension` array to make sure you have info in there.

Comment: more than enough duplicates to pick from http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=file+extension+php - please search before asking. And it's not like Google wouldn't have told you the solution as well.

Comment: @MihaiTodor please create your answer apart, i will accept. thank you

Comment: @Alex: I'm too lazy. Just accept the one with the upvote. It's the same as mine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex.
This would be pattern: "/.(\w+)$/"

This would be implementation:

```
if (preg_match('/.(\w+)\/?$/', $file, $matches) { $extension = $matches[1]; }
```

Comment: What if `$file = 'http://test.com/'` (notice the trailing "/")?

Comment: This is just for getting extension. After assigning extension he would add if (in_array()) block.
Ok, I've added the part for trailing slash.
Thanks.

Comment: There really is no need to use regex here. And the code posted by the OP is working (after fixing a missing semi-colon)

Comment: Now that's more like it, even though I'm not sure if the OP would want to get the 'bla' part from this: `$file = 'http://test.com/test.bla'` ;)

Comment: :D
My bad, I thought he is supporting files from other sources, strings with 'http://' part. With that in mind he could use 
'AND ! preg_match('/:\/\//', $file)'.
But Jocelyn is right, regex here is overkill.

Comment: @MihaiTodor do you mean that i have $file = 'http://test.com/test.bla' filepath wont work?

Comment: @Alex: It depends on what you want to extract. Just experiment, dude. You can run endless scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You have a missing ";"

Corrected line below. It should work fine. Tested.

```
$file = '/folder/subfolder/file.mp4';
```